# In Fallout 4, is stealing from enemies disliked?

Tags: fallout-4

Sorry if it's a stupid question. I haven't even made the character yet so I thought I'd ask before I invest time. Say my companion is Curie and I'm a sneaky character hiding from a raider in power armor. Will I see, "Curie disliked that" if I pickpocket the power core? Or if I steal people's weapons before I fight them? Am I shoehorned to use Cait if I have the pickpocket perk?

Comment: This question is a subquestion of the other, which lists all the likes and dislikes of each companion. Some dislike it, others don't care.

Comment: To me this sounds more like a clarification of what the particular dislike _means_ rather than who has it.

Comment: It is possible to steal and pickpocket without triggering the dislikes, even on a companion who dislikes the action. I'm not entirely sure what the criteria is, but it seems related to whether somehow would catch me. It could simply be a matter of being hidden from the companion so they don't notice (I've got high sneak, but no pickpocket yet). I've also heard you can tell your companion to sit in another room or something, so they're not in line-of-sight, to avoid the dislike from popping up.